# AngularJS ng-repeat: show data only when data is not false

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am using angular in an application and I'm showing data in my html page like this:

```
<div class="orderspresent" ng-cloak="">
 <div class="roworders" ng-controller="allorders" >
  <div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat= "o in orders">
   <div class="sm-st clearfix">
    <div class="sm-st-info">
     <i class="fa fa-square"></i>
      <span>{{o.customerName}}</span>
      <p>1 minutes</p>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat= "details in o.details">
        {{details.aantal}} x {{details.productTitle}}
        <br>+ {{details.extras}} 
        </li>     
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>             
 </div>
</div>
```

**JSON SAMPLE**

```
   {
    "49": {
           "orderID": 49,
           "customerID": 61,
           "orderDate": "2015-05-06 10:03:05",
           "orderDeliveryDate": "2015-05-06",
           "orderStatus": "prepare",
           "customerName": "Caroline",
           "details": [
                       {
                         "orderdetailID": 83,
                         "productTitle": "Sexy Teacher",
                         "productPrijs": 4,
                         "aantal": 2,
                         "extras": "Extra syrup, Soya milk",
                         "extrasPrice": 0.6
                       },
                       {
                         "orderdetailID": 84,
                         "productTitle": "Caramel Macchiato",
                         "productPrijs": 5.2,
                         "aantal": 2,
                         "extras": false,
                         "extrasPrice": 0
                      },
                      {
                         "orderdetailID": 85,
                         "productTitle": "The Coach",
                         "productPrijs": 3,
                         "aantal": 3,
                         "extras": false,
                         "extrasPrice": 0
                     },
                     {
                        "orderdetailID": 86,
                        "productTitle": "The Virgin",
                        "productPrijs": 3.2,
                        "aantal": 5,
                        "extras": "Extra syrup, Whipped cream, 3 espresso shots",
                        "extrasPrice": 2.4
                     }
                    ]
                }
    }
```

As you can see in the JSON sample above the {{details.extras}} value can sometimes be false. So now when I'm using {{details.extra}} it shows false in my html. But in that case I don't want anything to be shown there. Just blank.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: you could use an ```ng-hide``` tag, meaning that if it is false it will be hidden.

Comment: Use `ng-show`: `<span ng-show="details.extras">{{details.extras}}</span>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option for it is use [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf):

```
<span ng-if="details.extras">+ {{details.extras}}<span>
```

`ng-if` removes node from DOM. Smaller DOM - faster operations.

Comment: Faster operations is better, so thanks will accept in a minute

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow):

```
<br><span ng-show="details.extras">+ {{details.extras}}<span>
```

Comment: I would rather use ng-if here to not add unused elements to the DOM